# Copying rows whilst ignoring duplicates based on specific column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to copy rows from my table `call_list_row` whilst changing the column `listid`, but I only want to copy the row and change the `listid` if no other row with the `$new_list_id` already has a row with that particular `candid`.

This is the SQL I have to copy the rows and change the `listid`:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO call_list_row (listid,candid,date,byuser,status,emailed)
         SELECT '".$new_list_id."',candid,date,byuser,status,emailed 
         FROM call_list_row WHERE listid='".$list."'";
```

How can I modify this so that there will be no rows in the table that have the new `$new_list_id` with the same `candid`?

Comment: Check [`INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a unique index on the composite key `listid, candid`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX x_listid_candid ON call_list_row(listid, candid);
```

Then you can use `INSERT IGNORE`, so that if there's a row with that combination already in the table, the `INSERT` will be skipped with no error.

```
$sql= "INSERT IGNORE INTO call_list_row (listid,candid,date,byuser,status,emailed)
     SELECT '".$new_list_id."',candid,date,byuser,status,emailed 
     FROM call_list_row WHERE listid='".$list."'";
```

If you can't create this index (maybe duplicates are allowed, but you don't want to create any new duplicates in this procedure), you can check in the query.

```
$sql= "INSERT IGNORE INTO call_list_row (listid,candid,date,byuser,status,emailed)
     SELECT '".$new_list_id."',candid,date,byuser,status,emailed 
     FROM call_list_row AS c1 WHERE listid='".$list."'
     AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM call_list_row AS c2
        WHERE listid = '$new_list_id' AND c1.candid = c2.candid)";
```

Comment: Many thanks, I went for the second method as duplicates are allowed in general but not for this procedure